# Как закруглить края окна tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

Видел ответы для закругленной кнопки *tkinter*, закругленного окна на *PyQt*, 
но не видел про закругление окна для *tkinter*, чтобы интерфейс выглядел посовременней.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Это код шаблона для тех пользователей, которые используют Windows  и хотят, чтобы в главном окне были закругленные углы! https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/discussions/736